# rvalues c++0x and moving to heap

Tags: c++11

Okay, I've been reading about rvalues and they seem like a great idea, but something keeps bothering me about them. Particularly the claim that move allows us to steal resources and avoid copying.

I understand that move works and does avoid copying for everything that happens on the stack, but eventually most of the stuff done on the stack yields some value that we want copied into the heap and this is where I don't think move works.

Assuming that int has a move assignment operator, given the following code:

```
struct Foo
{
int x;
};

void doIt()
{
Foo* f = new Foo();
f->x = (2 + 4);
}
```

So in this example, the rvalue resulting from (2+4) can supposedly be moved over to f->x instead of copied. Okay, great. But f and consequently f->x is on the **heap** and that rvalue is on the **stack**. It seems impossible to avoid a copy. You cannot simply point f->x to the memory of the rvalue. That rvalue is going to be blown away as soon as doIt ends. A copy seems necessary.

So am I right that a copy will be made?
Or am I wrong?
Or did I completely misunderstand the rvalue concept?

Comment: It seems you are misunderstanding something. Moving is not magic and there is no quicker way of getting an int value somewhere than assigning/copying it.

Comment: @UncleBens Well I'm just trying to confirm that. I keep reading rvalues make things faster and avoid copying. But as in my example, I'm trying to confirm that copying indeed is required and rvalues only help in certain specific cases.

Comment: Moving objects of scalar types is equivalent to copying them. Moving becomes interesting with more complex types. What exactly happens if you move those is up to the class designer. You control this behaviour by defining your own move constructor.

Comment: Also, rvalues are not a new concept. We had rvalues and lvalues before. But C++0x gives us two reference types with which we can distinguish between rvalues and lvalues. The "valueness" (or value category) is a property of an expression. The basic idea of move semantics is that we can safely mutate rvalues without anyone noticing and/or caring.

Comment: If you're interested in a reasonably up-to-date article series on move semantics, check out http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, it probably would do a copy, but since the object only contains an `int`, that's not really much of a problem.

The times you care are generally when the object contains a pointer to some data that's allocated on the heap (regardless of where the object itself is allocated). In this case, avoiding allocating a new copy of that data is quite worthwhile (and since it's on the heap even if the object itself is on the stack, you can move it regardless of where the object itself is located).

Comment: Good point. Move can be used for stealing resources from one heap location to another. So we can have stack-to-stack moves. And heap-to-heap moves. But no stack-to-heap moves. Which is what I expected.

Comment: Surely you can move objects from stack to heap and the other way around. A move-enabled type typically doesn't care about where it lives. The storage concept is orthogonal to move semantics.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that **moving is not the opposite of copying** : moving is preferable because in most cases it will implement a *shallow copy* (instead of a *deep copy*).

If an object holds a pointer to some resource, a shallow copy is copying the pointer, while a deep copy is copying the data pointed to by the pointer. There always is copying involved : the question is "how deep must we go".

Your example only involves an `int` : there is no such thing as a *shallow* or *deep* copy of an int, so it is irrelevant here. So indeed, you are right to believe that moving only makes sense when dynamically allocated resources are involved.

Comment: Moving is certainly not *limited* to shallow copies. What a move constructor does is up to you the class designer.

Answer (score 1):

Um. Local variables are on the stack. That rvalue of yours will be optimized to `6` and the resulting binary will most likely have a `mov [dest], 6` in it.